# Arrange GridView's items in a center of the screen and close to each other

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-gridview

I want to arrange a set of images in a center of the screen, providing maximum possible dimensions  of each image. It should look like :

[image]

I use GridView and a custom adapter which computes size of ImageView. Here is code declaration of GridView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/mosaicView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And as a result it looks like :

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: That's a big resolution screenshot you posted. Are images big enough to fill more space?

Comment: Yes. They are generated at the server and their size is defined when arranging an appropriate ImageView.